# Can a company recoup money from a interviewee?

Tags: interviewing

My company would like to know if there is a legal form that a potential candidate can sign when we are paying for there flight and hotel and then they decide to not show and we are stuck with the bill.

Comment: Has your company tried to ask a lawyer about that? Seems to be more adequate than asking for kind strangers for legal opinions on a Workplace site.

Comment: Find a lawyer if you're after a form like that but consider the fact that you're going to lose out on hundreds, perhaps thousands, of highly-qualified candidates for every rare case where this saves you money. As a candidate I'd consider it a red flag that you don't know how to hire well.

Comment: Ok, that is a good thought Lilienthal

Comment: Does this happen to you often?  I have never heard of a no-show like that.

Comment: Seems to be a case of sunk cost fallacy to me. What if the candidate does show up and tanks the interview? Would you have a problem paying the bills even in that case? If you have already made up your mind to pay for the travel and hotel expenses, it doesn't really matter whether the candidate actually shows up or not. Besides,  you might be able to get at least some of the money back if the candidate cancels the trip as against the candidate shows up and puts in a mediocre performance.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **yes, you can**.

I signed one for a company I interviewed with way back in the day.  Its actually a reasonable thing to do from the companies perspective.

This will be dependent on local laws though, my experience is based in the USA.  Speak to a lawyer for more specifics as to how to word the document.

Comment: In Canada, I worked at one company that tried to get employees to sign such a liability waiver. The employer can try, but cannot force the employee to sign it (i.e. can't fire the employee for refusing to take on financial responsibility for the company). The company took away the "magic" company credit cards, and demanded employees pay up front for trips. Since the lead time on being reimbursed was 4 weeks **after** the trip concluded ($8,000/trip), the engineers just refused to travel, since it wasn't in the employment agreement. Trying to push this kind of policy will be painful.

Comment: I think this question is more specific to a candidate to come work for an employer, not an actual employee.